# In PY whoosh full text search engineer, how to create a query to find a value in a range?

Tags: python, whoosh

I am trying to find document by value in a specific range.
The official document doesn't give example for different types of fields and search methods.
Any smart guy can give me a link with more example and application? Any hint?

Thank you!

Here's my codes,

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser

schema = Schema(temperature=NUMERIC(float, stored=True))
ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)

writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(temperature = 32.3)
writer.commit()

with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("temperature", ix.schema).parse("temperature:>20.0") ## should be something like this
    print(searcher.search(query)[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range query syntax is `[START to END]` such as `START` and `END` are numbers representing the range bounds. `[ START to]` if no end is defined. `[to END]` if no start is defined.

In your case, for temperature greater than 20.0 use `temperature:[20.0 to]`. *Becarful no space between `to` and `]`*.

```
 query = QueryParser("temperature", ix.schema).parse("temperature:[ 20 to 1000 ]")
```

You can also use [`whoosh.query.NumericRange`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/query.html#whoosh.query.NumericRange):

> class whoosh.query.NumericRange (fieldname, start, end, startexcl=False, endexcl=False, boost=1.0, constantscore=True)

```
query = NumericRange(u'temperature', 20.0, None)
```

Ref: [Query lang - Ranges](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querylang.html?highlight=range#ranges)